# Populate Bootstrap Accordion with data from a mysql database in PHP / AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is what I'm trying to do.

I have an accordion, and I would like to populate the panel using ajax.

Here is what I have so far:

```
     <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
         <div class="panel panel-default" style="border-color: #fff!important;">  
             <?php foreach ( $arr2 as $departments ) {   ?>  
                <div class="panel-heading"   style="background-color: #6BA9CD!important;color: #fff!important;border-style: groove;border-width: 1px;border-color: #fff!important;border-radius: 8px;">
                                <h5 class="panel-title">
                                <a id="hover-tickets" data-department-id="<?php echo $departments['departmentid'];?>" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $departments['departmentid']?> ">
                                <?php echo $departments['name']; ?></a> <span class="total"><?php echo $departments['deptcount']; ?></span>
                                </h5>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapse<?php echo $departments['departmentid']?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body" style="border-top-color: #fff;"  id="department_<?php echo $departments['departmentid'];?>"> </div>
                            </div>
                
             <?php } ?>
        </div>
     </div>
```

I understand that I have to department id, however, I created this jquery function,

```
    $('#hover-tickets').click(function() {
                
    });
```

It either doesn't get the id nor does it read different accordions.

How would I get the jquery function to read the different accordion id in the jquery so I can pass the data in ajax?

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Comment: you can use only one id, use a class or target somthing different i.e `$("[data-department-id]")` instead of `$('#hover-tickets')` and traverse from what was clicked with `$(this)` inside the callback

Comment: is not really an ajax issue, you have not got to that part yet, perhaps you should change the question title.

Comment: You are right about the wrong question, however, your suggestion worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my resolution.

After the suggestion, here is what I did.

Instead of the following code:

```
   $('#hover-tickets').click(function() {
            
   });
```

to:

```
   $("[data-department-id]").click(function() {
         id = $(this).attr('data-department-id'); 
   });
```